# How execute numbers from 1 to 10 without loop in anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, function, anonymous-function

This is function but when executes this gave me just 1.

```js
(function(n, m) {
  // body...
  if (n <= m) {
    console.log(n);
    n++;
    (n, m);
  }
})(1, 10);
```

Comment: `(n, m)` isn’t a function call. Give the function a name.

Answer (score 3):

You can't recursively call an anonymous function; you have to give it a name instead (in which case it is no longer considered 'anonymous'):

```js
(function name(n, m) {
  // body...
  if (n <= m) {
    console.log(n);
    n++;
    name(n, m);
  }
})(1, 10);
```

Comment: **but why? explain please**

Comment: you can also use `arguments.callee`, but said functionality is deprecated and on its way out... you're better served giving the function a name.

Comment: Parentheses are used for other things in JavaScript, like holding expressions. Think `10 * (x + y)`. If `(x + y)` was referring to a so-called 'anonymous' function call, many basic math operations would become ambiguous. Are you calling the containing function with one parameter, or just adding `x` and `y`? That's why the language designers decided to force you to name your functions: so calling them can never be mistaken as attempting to do something else.

Comment: do you any useful subject about JS Function?

Comment: pdf or link about javascript functions? Explain please why anonymous function execute at once?

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842258/javascript-functions-how-can-i-start-beginning-to-understand-them

Comment: As for the question you edited onto your last comment: Anonymous functions don't have to execute immediately. You chose to execute it immediately by wrapping it in parentheses, and then using a second set of parentheses to call it with the arguments `1` and `10`. Condensed syntax: `(function { /* body */ })(1, 10)` is parsed like `(callable)(1, 10)` and then executed as `callable(1, 10)`, where `callable` is a reference to the function in question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `arguments.callee` which return definition of function being called

```js
(function(n, m) {
  // body...
  if (n <= m) {
    console.log(n);
    n++;
    arguments.callee(n, m);
  }
})(1, 10);
```

If you execute this you see the log

```js
(function(n, m) {
  // body...
  if (n <= m) {
    console.log(n);
    n++;
    console.log(arguments.callee);
  }
})(1, 10);
```

`arguments` is inbuilt array like object not exactly array which is injected by java script itself, it keep information about argument being passed to the function and many more... check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)

Comment: `arguments.callee` is currently tagged as `Deprecated` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee

Comment: what is argument.callee?

Comment: `arguments.callee` is not recommended in the latest version of JavaScript. In fact, it is forbidden in ES5+ strict mode. (See [this MDN article on arguments.callee](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee).)

Comment: @haxxxton  I agree with you it's deprecated but I was just trying to say that still It's possible

Answer (score 0):

You are not looping. Give a name to the function and the call that.

```js
(function test(n,m) {
        // body...
        if (n<=m) {
            console.log(n);
            n++;
            test(n,m);
        }
    })(1,10);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an anonymous function without a "loop" and displays numbers `n` to `m`

```js
(function(n, m) {
  Array.from({length:m}, (v,i) => console.log(i + n));
})(1, 10);
```

Comment: "Loop" in quotes is right, given that `Array.from()` will use a loop internally...

Answer (score 0):

Just use `while`

```js
(function(n, m) {
  // body...
  while (n <= m) {
    console.log(n);
    n++;
    (n, m);
  }
})(1, 10);
```

Comment: The question clearly says "without loop". It's a recursion exercise, you're not allowed to use `while`.

Comment: Damn I just skipped half the question. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't want to use loop

```
   (function(n, m) {
      // body...
      while (n <= m) {
        console.log(n);
        n++;
        (n, m);
      }
    })(1, 10);
```

`Loop` is always preferable than a `recursive function` as

1) - When a `recursive function` is called that function goes on the top of the stack,So if the `recursive function` is more than stack size at some point it will give you an error,(`Stack Overflow or Stack size exceeded`) ,To avoid this runtime error  always use loops rather than `recursive function`

Comment: "Always"? No. Also, you won't get stack overflows with tail-call optimisation. In any case, the OP is clearly working on a recursion exercise, so to ignore the problem they're having and say "never use recursion" isn't helping them at all.

Comment: Yes you are right but tail-call is not always solves your function tasks